# Overwriting data in file using array

Tags: java

I have an array in my program which stores data from a file upon application launch. The user has the ability to reserve a room but when they do I need to overwrite the data which is in the file I have read from with the user's email address at what room they have chosen.

This is my code which I have written that loops through the rooms and displays them as output for the user:

```
public static void ReserveRoom() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("ROOMS AVAILABLE");
    for (int i=0; i<rooms.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(rooms[i].toString());
    }
    System.out.println("\nEnter Room Number: ");
    int RoomNum = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your email: ");
    String eMail = input.next();
}'
```

This is the data in my file (The room numbers are the first column and I need to replace the 'free' in the last column with the user's email address once they place a booking).

```
101 Single 23.50 false false free
102 Single 23.50 false false free
103 Double 27.50 false false free
104 Double 27.50 false false free
105 Double 27.50 false false free
201 Single 23.50 true false free
202 Single 23.50 true false free
203 Double 27.50 true false free
204 Double 27.50 true false free
205 Double 27.50 true false free
301 Single 33.50 true true free
302 Single 33.50 true true free
303 Suite 60.00 true true free
304 Suite 60.00 true true free
305 Suite 60.00 true true free
306 Double 37.50 true true free
307 Double 37.50 true true free
```

So essentially, I need to replace the 'free' with the user's email address in the row with which room they have chosen.
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Replace the whole file.

Comment: Surely there's a more efficient way.

Comment: If it is a simple text file probably not. You could use a database instead. Or, if each line has the same length, try RandomAccessFile. If the length of a line is variable, than it's difficult.

Comment: You could save it as a JSONArray and just convert it everytime you need it and save it back to the file